# Fullwidth div that does not cause scrollbars

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a div element that is the same width as the screen so that I can have part of the background a different color than the rest. I would prefer that it would be with relative position, because with absolute I have to manually set it's vertical position, and that'd get messy, though the scrollbar wouldn't appear.

Right now, I do have it so that a div will take the area of the screen and can be a different color, but it causes a scrollbar to appear. The div is over the right side of the screen by using

`margin-right: -21px;`

but that causes the scrollbar. If I remove that, the bar goes away but then there is a portion of whitespace on the right side of the screen. Using

`overflow-x: hidden;`

will hide the scrollbar, but won't prevent scrolling horizontally.

How can I make it so the scrollbar doesn't appear and I can't scroll horizontally? I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2DDv/3/) for what I'm currently using.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions on how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are a few things you should fix up, removing the margin from the body, html will do the trick.

Get rid of the -21 margins and just add this style.

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2DDv/5/).

Comment: Oh wow, it was really that simple? I had tried using html{margin: 0px;}, but that didn't work. I suppose the px part may have caused a problem with it? Anyway, thanks a lot, that has fixed my problem.

Comment: @Zalerinian no, but you only removed it from the `<html>` element, but not from the `<body>`. `margin: 0` and `margin: 0px` are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

dirty trick that might work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
 <html>
   <head>
     <title> Bla! </title>
    <style>
        div.fullWidth { display:inline-block; width:100%; background-color:yellow }
        div.body { position:absolute; left:0px;  top:0px; background-color:green; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:auto}
        body { overflow:hidden; }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class='body'>
            line before the div
            <div class='fullWidth'> Line inside div</div>
            line after div
        </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```